# DialogFlow file upload to a server

Tags: webhooks, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Is it possible to upload a file from the local phone storage to a server using dialogflow assistant via webhooks?
If yes can you please tell me how will the workflow be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on integration. For Facebook Messenger you would have to add FACEBOOK_MEDIA event in your intent. On each file sent to your bot you will get a request where you can find file url in incoming json: `originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.data.message.attachments[0].payload.url`

I am not aware of similar events for other integrations.